# Which check box was selected

Tags: php, javascript

I have four rows per page. four rows which are parsed directly form mysql table. Each row has a check box. I want to know which check box was selected.
In the code shown below, it is saving the first row of the page only. So if I select the third row it will show as the first row selected. I'm using onchange method to know that something was selected but which one i don't know how to get it yet.

Could someone help?

```
<?php

    //limit for number of categories displayed per page
    $limit = 4;

    $categoriesNum= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('categoryTopic') FROM categories");   

    //number of current page
    $page =(isset($_GET['page']))? (int) $_GET['page'] :1;

    //calculate the current page number 
    $begin =($page - 1)* $limit; 

    //number of pages needed. 
    $pagesCount =ceil(mysql_result ($categoriesNum,0)/$limit);

    //Query up all the Categories with setting the Limit 
    $CategoryQuery = mysql_query ("SELECT categoryTopic From categories ORDER BY categoryTopic LIMIT $begin, $limit");

    //Place all categories in an array then loop through it displaying them one by one
    while ($query_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($CategoryQuery))
    {

        $category =$query_rows['categoryTopic'];  
        //echo $category; 
        //query all the subcategories that the current category has 
        $Sub = mysql_query ("SELECT categoryTopic FROM subcategories WHERE categoryTopic='$category'");             
        $Count = mysql_num_rows ($Sub); 

        echo  '<table width="85%" border="1"  cellpadding="0"; cellspacing="0" align="center">

        <tr>        
            <th width="23%" height="44" scope="col" align="left"> '.$query_rows['categoryTopic'].' <br><br><br></th>
            <th width="24%" scope="col">'.$Count.'</th>
            <th width="25%" scope="col"> 0 </th>
            <th width="28%" scope="col"> <form  name = "choose">
            <label><input type="checkbox" id ="check" value= '.$category.' onchange="handleChange(this);"></label>
        </tr>
    </table>';  
    }
    ?> 

<script type="text/jscript">
//this function will be called when user checks a check box. 

function handleChange(cb) {

//get the selected category 
var category = document.getElementById('check').value; 
document.write(category);
```

Answer (score 1):

look's like your are having **Duplicated ID's** on the page..

If each of the row has the **LABEL id="check"** , because ID in a page have to be unique it will always get the first element with that corresponding ID..

So it will always be the first row..

Instead try passing the this.value directly in your event

```
onchange="handleChange(this.value);

function handleChange(cb) {

document.write(cb);
```

This is a bad practice.. So try fixing the Duplicated ID's issue first..

Comment: if i give each row a different if how do I know which one was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you want to know how you can get the category (value of the checkbox) of the checkbox the user just clicked?

```
function handleChange(cb) {
  // get the selected category
  var category = cb.value;
  // ...
}
```

You give the current clicked checkbox to the `handleChange`-function via the `cb`-param. So if you want to get attributes of this checkbox, simply look for the attributes of the `cb`-object.

Answer (score 0):

You are having multiple rows with same id which makes your HTML invalid. To avoid this you should change your javascript code to

```
function handleChange(cb) {
//get the selected category 
var category = cb.value; 
document.write(category);
}
```